# Python logging module: logger is repeating the message more and more as I run the script

Tags: python, logging, spyder

So I have been having this weird problem in my Spyder IDE (and only in Spyder).
I initialize a logger using the logging module, and each time I run the script the messages are printed in more and more times (once on the first try, twice on the second, thrice on the third, etc...). Any ideas why?
The code:

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handle = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(handle)
handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handle.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.warning('Testing')
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is what I see in my console after two tries:

logger.warning('Testing')
2020-09-30 15:34:34,763 - WARNING - Testing

logger.warning('Testing')
2020-09-30 15:34:38,476 - WARNING - Testing
2020-09-30 15:34:38,476 - WARNING - Testing

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: The code works fine

Comment: Elaborate your uses and running mechanisms

Comment: I literally just run the code snippet by clicking the run script button...

Comment: This happens because you are not removing the handler. Every time you call addHandler, it adds a new handler, and since they are never cleared, they all write the same message. Try closing the handler `handle.close()` and removing it `logger.removeHandler(handle)`, at the end of the script. @LoloTheKid

Comment: Closing and removing the handler didn't work either... If I close spyder and start it up again I start back with one message, but then they keep multiplying with each run script I do... And clearing variables doesn't change anything either...

Comment: I tried your code snippet on Spyder IDE, and it did show multiple messages every time I run the script. However, adding `logger.removeHandler(handle)` fixed the issue. If that's exactly how you're using your logger, it should work. Did you test in a new console?

Answer (score 0):

The logging module uses a static logger object that lives in your python session. So, every time you run your script, `addHandler` will add a new handler to `logger.handlers`. You can add a line to your script that prints `logger.handlers` and check.

```py
...
logger.addHandler(handle)
print(logger.handlers)
...
```

And every time you call `logger.warning` the message will be printed as many times as the number of handlers you have.

To fix this you need to remove the handler:

```py
...
logger.warning('Testing')
logger.removeHandler(handle)
```

Another fix is to check if you already have a handler before adding a new one. This way you will only have one handler, and you won't need to remove it.

```py
...
if not logger.handlers:
    handle = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handle.setFormatter(formatter)
    handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handle)
...
```

You could also look into removing all handlers first.